# Get specific table name in all databases SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a system with multiple databases. All databases are at one SQL Server instance. I am trying to find a table (like) some name, but don't know the exact name and where it exists in all databases. Code below is what I am currently using but I have to be changing the database name in each instance. any way i can have it step through all, and if I could provide a specific table name

```
USE your_database
SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

Comment: You should probably create a Utility db and from there gather all the table information that you require and insert it there so you will have one place where you can do aggregate type queries. Otherwise you might have to use a tool like Linqpad to query across multiple dbs at the same time.

Comment: give me a 5 min, i am about to share you with the solution

Comment: i have found that this is duplicate question